# Using multiple images for face recognition using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition

I have been trying to create a face recognition system using OpenCV's face_recognition module.
Every tutorial on the internet uses one image for a single person. I want to use multiple photos of the same person.
Inside the known_faces directory, there are 4 folders, each folder containing 10 images of the same person.

```
import face_recognition
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import load

KNOWN_FACES_DIR = 'known_faces'
TOLERANCE = 0.4
FRAME_THICKNESS = 3
FONT_THICKNESS = 2
MODEL = 'cnn'
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


print('Encoding faces...')
known_faces = []
known_names = []

for name in os.listdir(KNOWN_FACES_DIR):
    for filename in os.listdir(f'{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}'):
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}/{filename}')
        box = face_recognition.face_locations(image,model=MODEL)[0]
        encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image,box)[0]
        known_faces.append(encoding)
        known_names.append(name)

print(known_faces)

np.save('face_repr.npy', known_faces)
np.save('labels.npy', known_names)
```

Let's take the name of flowers inside directories A, B, C, D
If I print the known_faces the output is:
[ 'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B',
'C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C',
'D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D' ]

So instead of creating encoding of 4 people, it creates for 40 people (for 40 images).
I want 4 encoding for 4 people with 40 images.
Please Help!

Comment: "OpenCV's face_recognition module" -- no, it's not an opencv module

Comment: "I want 4 encoding for 4 people with 40 images." -- maybe you misunderstood something. this is just a "feature preprocessor". you input a (single) image, and receive a (single) feature vector